# Derive sequencing probabilities from univariate data

Tags: time-series, probability, sequential-analysis, univariate, sequential-pattern-mining

Given a variable measured sequentially e.g. -6,-3,0,2,-3,1,-5,7,-47.. etc, what are some methods to derive some reliable sequencing probabilities?
e.g. if i-2>0 and i-1 >0 then i>0 etc.

Comment: Are you looking for patterns in the sequence? I don't understand what reliable sequencing probabilities means.

Comment: Yes, essentially.

Comment: Are you given a long sequence and looking to see what patterns repeat? How do you pick the pattern? I can see a probability coming about if you see part of the specified sequence start but not complete versus when it does repeat.  If that is the case you could estimate the probability by taking sequences complete and dividing it by sequences started but not completed + sequences completed.  This may not be what you mean but it is the only way I can make sense of your question.